# What is the name of the paper of the result of the ECG?

Tags: word-request

What is the name of the paper of the result of the ECG?

I saw someone (non native English speaker) who called it "**tracing**", I would like to ensure it and to know if there are alternatives for that.

[image: picture of a paper with ECG tracings on it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECG plots (**tracings**) are usually drawn on **graph paper**.
The paper is moved below a pen so the x-axis (paper direction) corresponds to time and spiking can be observed or any irregularities.

Please see more [**here**](http://www.practicalclinicalskills.com/ekg-lesson.aspx?coursecaseorder=1&courseid=301)

Answer (score 2):

Having worked with them for many years, I can tell you confidently that it's called simply the ECG - or in the USA, the EKG.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the ECG- the strip of paper together with the information on it- can be referred to as a **trace**.